# Selected option not set in EntityType::class formfield symfony3

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony, formbuilder

I'm very new at working with a framework like symfony, but I must say that i am turning in to a fan quite fast. Unfortunately i'm totally stuck for the last few days in a row.

**The Context**
I'm trying to refactor my old-school php CMS to the symfony3 framework. A user can manage his pages by adding en editing them. Adding a new page to the database works like a charm. Editing a page is also working fine, except one small part of it. The form prefills al fields like it should and a post will edit the entity.
But... for some reason the selectbox won't pre-select with the selected templatetype. This list is build with use of the EntityType::class and fetches the available data from the database by using AppBundle:Templates.

A piece of the code i use for loading and building the form:

```
    // Fetch selected page
    $page = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:PageMan')->find($id);        

    // Generate form
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($page)
      ->add('templateId', EntityType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Template type',
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Templates',
        'placeholder' => 'Kies een template',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        'choice_value' => 'id',
        'multiple' => false,
        'expanded' => false,
        'required' => true,
       ))->getForm();
```

The last few days i have tried every possibility i could think of and google. I've also checked the following:

- *templateId* is filled with a value after loading the repository. When I change the field to a plain textfield, the value is shown.
- *AppBundle:Templates* returns unique values (only two entity's in the database with id 1 and 2)
- The selected="selected" attribute is set when posting (and not redirecting away)
- Removing cashe doesn't solve the problem

At his moment i'm out of possible solutions, hope some one can help. It could be something so simple, but i'm just not seeing it anymore.

**--Update--**
Just found the following inconsistency in a vardump of the generated form. In the 'name'-object you see modelData, normData and viewData pre-filled. But 'templateId' misses content in viewData.

[screenshot vardump formbuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJABV.png)

In the documentation of symfony it states the folowing:

> **View Data** - This is the format that's used to fill in the form fields themselves. It's also the format in which the user will submit the data. When you call Form::submit($data), the $data is in the "view" data format. [Source](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html)

This could be a possible leed to a solution.

**--Update 2--**
Just hardcoded $this->viewData in \vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php to a hardcoded value that is present in the selectbox. This adds a value to the empty setting as mentioned in the the update above. Now the default value gets selected as it should. I'm going to follow this variable in the code. Hope to find the reason why it doesnt get prefilled.

Comment: Does `templateId` exist in your PageMan Entity?

Comment: @AlvinBunk, thank you for your quick response. Yes is does. Here is a vardump that i printed on pageload
`PageMan {#379 ▼
  -id: 6
  -name: "Nieuwe naam"
  -templateId: "2"
  -url: "nieuwe_url"
  -title: "plaatjes"
  -inMenu: true
  -active: true
  -sitemap: true
  -metaDescr: "fdgfdgfdg"
  -metaKeywords: "fdgf"
}` i've tried it as a string and int

Comment: I'm wondering if `'choice_value' => $page->getId(),` would get rid of the error? Let me know, If it works, I'll post as the answer.

Comment: To bad, that doesn't work either. Also $page contains the posted variables and therefor only one id. I tried `'choice_value' => 'getId',` and this fills the `value=""` attr of the options well, but doesn't select the one with value 2, as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed my problem. Don't know if it's the official way, but in my case it works like a charm.

In my EntityType setting, i'm now passing `'data' => $page,` as an extra object to the formbuilder. This results in viewData being filled with a value and that was what i needed to get a pre-selectid selectbox on pageload.

Here the final snippet:

```
            ->add('templateId', EntityType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Template type',
            'class' => TemplateMan::class,
            'placeholder' => 'Kies een template',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'choice_value' => 'templateId',
            'data' => $page,
            'data_class' => null,
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'required' => true,
        ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually `choice_value` is callable, so you can make a function:

```
'choice_value' => function($page){
    return strval( $page->getId() );
}
```

I think that might work in this case. Please try it.

Comment: This gives the following error: Call to a member function getId() on integer

Comment: Probably because `choice_value` requires a string value. I edited my code. Make sure you read the [EntityType documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) before responding, because you might be able to figure out the problem on your own. I'm only trying to help.

Comment: Thanks man, ill will look in to the documentation. I've read it multiple times. But you never know what i missed out ;)! Thanks a lot for your help.